# Oracle: How to do an insert into... select... where there is no table being queried

Tags: oracle

I have an insert statement that takes all its values from local variables or literal constants:

```
    INSERT INTO SampleTestLimits 
    (AuditNumber 
    ,LimitNumber 
    ,ComponentRow 
    ,ComponentColumn
--etc
    ) 
    SELECT 1 
    ,varLimitNumber 
    ,varComponentRow 
    ,varComponentColumn
--etc
 ;
```

but the problem is that I get an error "Missing FROM".

I guessed that this is because there is no table associated with the Select, and I tried ending the query with

```
FROM DUAL;
```

but that doesn't work (possibly because DUAL is a single row, single column pseudo-table, or so I understand).

I can do this quite easily in Sql Server, but how can I do what I want to achieve in Oracle?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert data from local variables you should use the VALUES clause:

```
INSERT INTO SampleTestLimits 
  (AuditNumber 
  ,LimitNumber 
  ,ComponentRow 
  ,ComponentColumn
  --etc
  ) 
VALUES
  (1
  ,varLimitNumber 
  ,varComponentRow 
  ,varComponentColumn
  --etc
  );
```

Comment: Although `SELECT 1,varLimitNumber ,varComponentRow ,varComponentColumn FROM DUAL` should work

Comment: That is correct but it will only add overhead for executing a SELECT as well as an INSERT.

Comment: I agree that using VALUES is the elegant solution. Maybe instead of saying "you have to use the VALUES".. it hsould be 'should use'

Comment: Yes you are right, both are functionally correct. I've changed it.

Comment: Doh! Of course. I'm optimising an insert statement in a stored procedure in both Sql Server and Oracle systems that previously actually queried a table, but I realised that the query was redundant because all the values were already held in local variables. Because the Select continued to work in Sql Server, I foolishly assumed it was the way to go in Oracle. Clearly not!